# Remote Desktop Connection not working Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I'm having trouble setting up Remote Desktop Connection at work to a Windows 7 Pro SP1 machine.

I've enabled RD, checked the services and firewall rules. I've also tried numerous of potential fixes I've found on Stack Exchange/MS TechNet etc, without success.
For example deleting the RD certificate on the Windows 7 machine.
Still, the connection cannot be established.

I'm trying to connect from a Windows 8.1 Pro machine.
Note: it does work the other way around and it does work to other computers in the network.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you try? Are you getting a connection failed error immediately, is it timing out, are you getting an authentication error, or is it something else?

Comment: It shows 'Initiating remote connection..' for a while and then it pops up the following:
Remote Desktop can’t connect to the remote computer for one of these reasons:

1) Remote access to the server is not enabled
2) The remote computer is turned off
3) The remote computer is not available on the network

Comment: Are you able to telnet to itself using port 3389 (command prompt > telnet localhost 3389)? Then try to telnet from the windows 8.1 (command prompt > telnet windows7ipaddress 3389)? Should give us some more clues as to where the problem is.

Comment: I guess you're on to something, the device cannot telnet to itself: 'Connection failed'.
When trying from the W8.1 machine: 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you ping the windows 7 machine from the windows 8 machine? run cmd > ping "name or IP of your computer"

Comment: *"name or IP of your windows 7 machine" sorry

Comment: I can ping the machine using its domain name.

Comment: hmm could you try the IP?

Comment: I can also ping to the IP.

Comment: right so DHCP is out of the question, try looking in allow a program through the firewall I know you've checked but I don't know where check that all remote services are checked on the both machines if this works then uncheck them one at a time to see which ones you need running

Comment: I've enabled Remote Desktop and RemoteFX in the Windows Firewall for all network types.
(Why can't I find the RemoteFX application on my W8.1Pro machine?)
All the services are running, still unable to connect.
Even when Windows Firewall is completely disabled on the W7 machine I still cannot connect to it.

Comment: can you ping the server from your windows 7 machine?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the W8.1Pro machine from the W7 machine.

Comment: no your server so you can confirm that it is connected to the network properly

Comment: Yes, I can also ping to the W7 machine from the domain server.

Comment: I can also ping the server from the W7 machine.

Comment: When scanning the W7 machine from the W8.1 machine with Nmap I get 'filtered' result for port 3389, yet RD is enabled. So this means 'something' is blocking it I guess. How can I figure out what process is responsible?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with 2 win 7 x64 machine one with ultimate ed one with pro.

using ultimate i can't remote to the professional... but from pro i can connect to ultimate?!?!
and after i connect from pro to ultimate even without do the login... then i can connect from ultimate to pro!?!?!?

the workaround: using team viewer 9 i launch the pro to ultimate remote desktop, then i can connect ultimato to pro....

i tryed ultra vnc, had the same problem of remote desktop...